# $H=V’AV$, does $A$ and $H$ have the same eigenvalue?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

if $H=V’AV$, the columns of $V$ are orthonormal . $V’$ is the transpose of $V$

$n>m$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, H\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}, V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.

I found that $A$ and $H$ has the same eigenvalue:

if $Hu=\lambda u$, then $V’AVu=\lambda u$, hence $AVu=\lambda Vu$, that is to say: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Similarly, all $A$’s eigenvalue is also the eigenvalue of $H$ since $A=VHV’$.

my question is: why $H$ and $A$ have the same eigenvalue while $A$ has $n$ eigenvalues and $H$ has $m$ eigenvalues ($m\neq n$)?

Comment: When you say the columns of $V$ are standard orthogonal, I would take that to mean $V=I$ (the standard basis).  Do you mean that the columns of $V$ are orthonormal?

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes, I edited my question.

Comment: Which is bigger, $m$ or $n?$

Comment: @WillJagy $n>m$

Comment: no, if $n > m$ then $A$ is of size $n \times n$ but $rank(A) = rank(H) \le m$, hence $A$ always has the eigenvalue $0$ (with multiplicity $n-rank(H)$) even if $H$ doesn't (i.e. if $rank(H) = m$)

Comment: @user1952009 but according to the reasoning above, if 0 is the eigenvalue of $A$, it must be the eigenvalue of $H$, is there something wrong?

Comment: everything. try with $V = I_{n \times m}$ i.e. with $H$ the $m \times m$ sub-matrix  of $A$

Comment: when you write $A x = \lambda x \implies V^T A V (V^Tx) = \lambda V^Tx$ it is true in the general case only if $V V^T = I$ which is true when  $n > m$ :

Comment: @user1952009 but can we prove that H's eigenvalue is A's eigenvalue? according to your comments, there seems to be no relationship between the eigenvalue of A and H?

Comment: ... $V V^T \ne I$ so not all the eigenvalues of $A$ are transferred to $H$,  but $V^T V = I$ hence all the eigenvalues of $H$ are transferred to $A$... that's what I explained above : $A$ has the eigenvalues of $H$ plus the eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n - m$

Comment: @user1952009 wait,  I can't deduce $AVu=\lambda Vu$ from $V’AVu=\lambda u$ since $VV'\neq I$

Comment: if $PQ = I$ and $H u = \lambda u$ then $ Q H P Q u = \lambda Q u$  hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Q H P$, that's all you can say.

Comment: @user1952009 why $H=V'AV\implies A=VHV'$ ($VV'\neq I$)